# How to read from a char array (array of names)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

Guys I have used this to read in data successfully from a file.

```
void read(FILE *fPtr, int *a, int *b, char **c, int size)
{
    char line[100];
    int num = 0;

    while ( fgets(line, 99, fPtr) && num < size )
    {       
        // This is a names array
        c[num] = strtok (line, " ");        
        // here the name prints out fine
        a[num] = atoi(strtok (NULL, " \n"));
        b[num] = atoi(strtok (NULL, " \n"));

        num++;
    }

}
```

But I am unable to read properly from this char ** array.

main function:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int g[30];
    int a[30];
    char *names[30];    

    // Open file 
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    read(
        fp, g, a, 
        names, 30 );

    printf("%s\n", player_names[0]);

    printThis(
        g, a,
        names, 30 );

    return 0;
}
```

print this:

```
void printThis(int* g, int* a, char** n, int s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", n[i]);
}
```

This totally does not print names! it prints just @  some space chars and @. Why isn't it printing anything. Is it not the proper way for accessing char arrays?

[image]

Comment: `c[num] = strtok (line, " ");` : This store address of part of local buffer.

Comment: `char line[100];` is a local variable so goes out of scope when the function is exit. The pointers are then pointing to memory that no longer belongs to you. Not only, but also even if `char line[100];` was global, each line will overwrite the data of the previous line - you need also to copy the data in some way.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by `printf("%s\n", player_names[0]);` ?

Comment: `fgets` reserves space for the *nul-byte* (unlike `scanf`) so `fgets(line, 100, fPtr)` or  `fgets(line, sizeof line, fPtr)` are proper. Also, avoid `atoi` it provides no way to *validate* the conversion, use `strtol` instead.

Comment: You also should NOT declare a function (e.g. `read`) with the same name as a C-Standard Library function (e.g. `read`).

Comment: @RohanKumar Trying to print all names in that array.

Comment: @WeatherVane So declaring a global line variable would do fix the issue?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this is not my own program and not  open-source either, I had to rename stuff before I paste them into SOF

Comment: @PrimeHero no, I said *even if `char line[100];` was global, each line will overwrite the data of the previous line - you need also to copy the data in some way.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where, as has been addressed in the comments, you were expecting to assign `c[num] = strtok (line, " ");`, you found the values in `names` no longer pointed to anything meaningful. When you declare a variable within a function, unless you dynamically allocate storage for the variable (e.g. with `malloc`), the variable only survives for the lifetime of the function. Why?

When a function is called a separate area of memory is created for the execution of the function called the *function stack frame*. That memory holds the variables declared within the function. When the function returns, the stack frame is destroyed (actually just released for reuse as required). Any variables declared local to the function are no longer available for access.

In your case, `strtok` returns a pointer to the beginning of a token within `line` (or `NULL` if no token in found). Upon function `return`, the pointer returned by `strtok` points to memory that has been release for reuse and can no longer be accessed within the calling function (`main` here) -- thus your problem.

How do I fix this? Well, there are many ways. The first, easiest solution, is just to dynamically allocate storage for the names, and make a copy of the tokens found by `strtok` and store them within the memory you have allocated. That memory will survive `return` and can be validly accessed in the caller. (you must remember to free the memory when it is no longer needed)

You also need to have your `read` (my `readfp` below) function return a meaningful value rather than `void`. It would be nice to know how many records were actually filled. If you change the function type to `int`, then you can return `num` and know how many records (e.g. `name[x] a[x] & g[x]` combination) were filled.

Wait... `num` was declared local to `read`, why can I return it? Every function can always return a value of its own `type`. If you declare `int read (...)`, `read` can return an `int` value and its survives return due to the calling convention between caller and callee.

Putting those pieces together, and using `strtol` in place of `atoi` for `int` conversions (and making it easy by creating a separate function to handle and **validate** the conversions), you could do something similar to the following. Also note that `main` takes *arguments* which you can make use of to pass a filename to open, rather than hardcoding, e.g. `fopen("input.txt", "r")`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

/* define constants for use below */ 
enum { BASE = 10, MAXP = 30, MAXL = 100 };

int readfp (FILE *fp, int *a, int *b, char **c, int size);
int xstrtol (char *s, int base);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int g[MAXP] = {0},
        a[MAXP] = {0},
        n = 0;
    char *names[MAXP] = {NULL};    
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    n = readfp (fp, g, a, names, MAXP );

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    if (n)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf ("%-30s %8d %8d\n", names[i], g[i], a[i]);
            free (names[i]);    /* free memory allocated by strdup */
        }

    return 0;
}

int readfp (FILE *fp, int *a, int *b, char **c, int size)
{
    char line[MAXL] = "";
    int num = 0;

    while (num < size && fgets (line, sizeof line, fp))
    {       
        char *delim = " \t\n",
            *tmp = strtok (line, delim);
        int itmp = 0;

        if (tmp)
            c[num] = strdup (tmp);  /* allocate storage and copy tmp */
        else {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: strtok failed - c[%d].\n", num);
            break;
        }

        if ((tmp = strtok (NULL, delim)) && (itmp = xstrtol (tmp, BASE)))
            a[num] = itmp;
        else {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: strtok failed - a[%d].\n", num);
            break;
        }

        if ((tmp = strtok (NULL, delim)) && (itmp = xstrtol (tmp, BASE)))
            b[num] = itmp;
        else {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: strtok failed - b[%d].\n", num);
            break;
        }

        num++;
    }

    return num;
}

int xstrtol (char *s, int base) 
{
    errno = 0;
    char *endptr = NULL;
    long v = strtol (s, &endptr, base);

    if (errno) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xstrtol() error: over/underflow detected.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (s == endptr && v == 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xstrtol() error: no digits found.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (v < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < v) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xstrtol() error: out of range of integer.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return (int)v;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/names.txt
Ryan,Elizabeth     62  325
McIntyre,Osborne   84  326
DuMond,Kristin     18  327
Larson,Lois        42  328
Thorpe,Trinity     15  329
Ruiz,Pedro         35  330
Ali,Mohammed       60  331
Vashti,Indura      20  332
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readnames <dat/names.txt
Ryan,Elizabeth                       62      325
McIntyre,Osborne                     84      326
DuMond,Kristin                       18      327
Larson,Lois                          42      328
Thorpe,Trinity                       15      329
Ruiz,Pedro                           35      330
Ali,Mohammed                         60      331
Vashti,Indura                        20      332
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block of memory, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/readnames <dat/names.txt
==11303== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11303== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11303== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11303== Command: ./bin/readnames
==11303==
Ryan,Elizabeth                       62      325
McIntyre,Osborne                     84      326
DuMond,Kristin                       18      327
Larson,Lois                          42      328
Thorpe,Trinity                       15      329
Ruiz,Pedro                           35      330
Ali,Mohammed                         60      331
Vashti,Indura                        20      332
==11303==
==11303== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11303==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11303==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 112 bytes allocated
==11303==
==11303== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11303==
==11303== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11303== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of issues in your code as mentioned by the people in comments. But you should carefully consider the comment by Weather Vane. Right now your names array is `char *names[30]`; and you assign address of a local variable to it. You need to copy the data in some way(as line goes out of scope after function call). So i would suggest changing your `names` array to something like :

```
char names[30][WORD_LEN];
```

For copying data you might need something like `strcpy`. I changed your code a bit and was able to see the desired result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORD_LEN 100

void read(FILE *fPtr, int *a, int *b, char c[][WORD_LEN], int size)
{
    char line[100];
    int num = 0;

    while ( fgets(line, 99, fPtr) && num < size ) {       
        // This is a names array
        //strcpy(c[num], strtok (line, " "));

        // here the name prints out fine
        // !avoid atoi, use sscanf instead
        //a[num] = atoi(strtok (NULL, " "));
        //b[num] = atoi(strtok (NULL, " "));

        sscanf(line, "%s%d%d", c[num], &a[num], &b[num]);
        num++;
    }
}

void printThis(int* g, int* a, char n[][WORD_LEN], int s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        printf("%s %d %d\n", n[i], a[i], g[i]);
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int g[30];
    int a[30];
    char names[30][WORD_LEN];    

    // Open file 
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    read(fp, g, a, names, 30 );
    printThis(g, a, names, 30 );
    return 0;
}
```

I changed the file structure to space delimited tokens, and i was able to see the names :

```
~/work : $ cat input.txt 
Rohan 120000 4300000
Prashant 12 43
~/work : $ g++ readCharArray.c 
~/work : $ ./a.out 
Rohan 4300000 120000
Prashant 43 12
~/work : $
```

Comment: So there is no way outta this using just char ** ?

Comment: @PrimeHero: Even if you make your `char line[100]` global you would still end up assigning same values to different places of `char *names[]`. Remember that strings can't be copied via assignments(Just addresses are assigned). You need memory for storing strings and `char *names[]` is just an array of character pointers. By the way `char names[][]` is char ** internally ;) , You can also dynamically assign memory for word lengths but it would essentially be the same thing as taking  up the former option.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc got it!